# How to Get followers Ids who don't make their tweets private

Tags: c#, linq-to-twitter

I want to get all followers ids who don't make their tweets private. What modification needs in the query

```
 var friends = await twitterCtx.Friendship
                    .Where(f => f.Type == FriendshipType.FollowerIDs
                             && f.UserID == twitterUserId.ToString()
                             && f.Count == maxFollowersToRetrieve
                             && f.Cursor == nextCursor)
                     .Select(f => f).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

FollowerIDs query will only give you User IDs. You can use FollowerList instead. The Friendship response has a property named Users that is a collection of User. Each User entity has a property named Protected that is set to true if the user makes their tweets private.